# Troubles with joining tables in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to take a crystal report sql and convert it so I can use it in excel.  I'm having troubles with the syntax of the joining statements in Excel.  I can do a couple of tables individually, but cant combine them.

*From crystal reports:  What I'm trying to copy:*

```
SELECT "Material_Req"."Job", "Material_Req"."Pick_Buy_Indicator", "Material_Req"."Material", "Material_Req"."Description", "Material_Req"."Vendor_Reference", "PO_Detail"."PO", "Material_Req"."Est_Qty", "Source"."Act_Qty", "PO_Header"."Vendor", "PO_Detail"."Due_Date"
 FROM   (("PRODUCTION"."dbo"."Material_Req" "Material_Req" LEFT OUTER JOIN "PRODUCTION"."dbo"."Source" "Source" ON "Material_Req"."Material_Req"="Source"."Material_Req") LEFT OUTER JOIN "PRODUCTION"."dbo"."PO_Detail" "PO_Detail" ON "Source"."PO_Detail"="PO_Detail"."PO_Detail") LEFT OUTER JOIN "PRODUCTION"."dbo"."PO_Header" "PO_Header" ON "PO_Detail"."PO"="PO_Header"."PO"
 WHERE  "Material_Req"."Pick_Buy_Indicator"='b' AND "Material_Req"."Est_Qty">"Source"."Act_Qty"
 ORDER BY "Material_Req"."Job"
```

*Previous one that worked:*

```
sqlMatlReq = "select job.job,  material_req.vendor_reference, material_req.Material,'' As Description, material_req.Vendor," _
        & "(material_req.est_qty) As Qty, (material_req.act_qty) As Qty,   " _
        & "material_req.due_date, " _
        & " material_req.status " _
        & "from (material_req inner join job on material_req.job=job.job) " _
        & "left join material on material_req.material=material.material " _
        & "where material.material is not null " _
        & "and job.part_number is not null " _
        & "and Job.Status in('Active') " _
        & "and material_req.act_qty in('0') " _
        & "Union all " _
        & "select job.job, material_req.vendor_reference, material_req.Material, material_req.description, material_req.Vendor," _
        & "(material_req.est_qty), (material_req.act_qty) As Qty," _
        & " material_req.due_date, material_req.status " _
        & "from (material_req inner join job on material_req.job=job.job) " _
        & "left join material on material_req.material=material.material " _
        & "where material.material is null " _
        & "and job.part_number is not null " _
        & "and Job.Status in('Active') " _
        & "and material_req.act_qty in('0') " _
        & "order by job.job;"
```

*As far as I got:  having troubles combining the three*

```
'sqlMatlReq = "select job.job, material_req.material, material_req.Vendor_Reference, material_req.description, material_req.Est_Qty  " _
      '& "from (material_req inner join job on material_req.job=job.job) " _

'sqlMatlReq = "select source.Act_Qty, PO_Detail.PO, PO_Detail.Due_Date " _
      '& "from source left outer join PO_Detail on source.Act_qty=PO_Detail.PO_Detail "

'sqlMatlReq = "select PO_Header.vendor " _
      '& "from PO_Header"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL Server Stored Procedures for Use With Crystal Reports

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE sp_SampleProcedure
    AS
 
 BEGIN 
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT table_catalog, table_schema, table_name, table_type
   FROM tbldm.information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema = 'dbo'
    AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE';

 END;
```

> Where any query you would like to see supplying data to the Crystal Reports client should be represented by the last `SELECT` statement issued in the SQL Server STORED procedure.  This example points to the SQL data dictionary of Table Names and Types.

1. Define a DSN connection between the Crystal Reports client and the SQL Database Server.  There may already be one of other reports were designed before this.
2. Stored procedures should show up in its schema catalog alongside the other objects typically found by the Crystal report writer when selecting db objects to use.
3. Note, procedures can be parametrized and their input variables used throughout the procedure itself.